# Laravel - authenticating user without logging in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In laravel 5.4 is it possible to authenticate user without logging him in? From laravel doc the closest thing i could find was:

```
Auth::once($credentials)
```

But this still logged the user in for the duriation of that one request. All i need is to just know if user with that email and password exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Auth::attempt` function with third parameter as `false` which is for login

```
 $email=$request->email;
 $password=$request->password;
 if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$email, 'password'=>$password],false,false))
   {
        echo "found":
    }else {
        echo "not found";
   }
```

Check this https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.html#method_attempt

Or use `Auth::validate`

https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.html#method_validate

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to check if User exist with given credentials do it like this:

```
//get the user by email
$user = User::where('email',$email)->first();
if($user !== null){
// if user is found, check if password match against given text
   $isRightPassword = Hash::verify($password,$user->password);
}
```

The above code will not authenticate User.